Help me match this drywall texture!
DIY homeowner here.
I've searched and searched, but haven't been able to find anything that matches this drywall texture.  The crests are very rounded and gentle and fairly consistent in width and height. It flows in large organic patterns, with fairly smooth wall between.
I've been trying to use a 8" trowel or a 6" taping knife to "cut" these edges.  I'm using USG Ultralight, thinned down to about where its just dripping off of the knife.  I'll apply a 1/16" or so layer of mud and flatten it with a big 12" trowel.  Then, I try to work a knife or smaller trowel through to create these ridges.
I find that I'm cutting the mud with the edge of my knife, creating a raised lip that then collapses on itself.  it forms a sharp ridge and very inconsistent thickness.
I'm tempted to go out and try it either with a pool trowel or a rubber float.
In this last go at it, I accidentally discovered that I can try to "push" the mud to flow into these more organic and softer lines.  They weren't as pronounced as the existing textures, but maybe my mud isn't wet enough.  Perhaps I can use a very wet mud and wet sponge; but I'm not sure that it will create the drywall texture I'm looking for.
Any tips would be appreciated!




That is done with a wide 6,8 or 10 inch taping knife. ( depending on width of peaks)
A layer of plaster or drywall compound is put down about 1/8 inch thick.
( the thickness does not need to be uniform)
Take the knife and press it into the compound and move it in a sweeping motion.
How much pressure you use will change the height and width of the peaks.
If the peaks are too sharp or high when all is dry you can sand them lightly with 300 grit on a sanding block.
This takes a great amount of patience and practice.  The exact effect is like an individuals signature.

Can you give some tips or advice as to how wet the mud should be?  Is ultralight better for this, or should i get some Plus3?  Will it help if i sand down the edges of the knife?

Don't over think this.   Definitely do not sand down the edge of your knives.    I have used all purpose for my texturing.  For this type You want the mud to be a little stiffer than peanut butter.  Again you need to experiment and practice to see exactly what works to match the closest
